# What does nslookup -type=ns really do?

Tags: nslookup

I know my question is a newbie answer. I been looking at the websites, but I can't really get a good answer or at least an answer that I can understand. So lets say I type in 'nslookup www.mit.edu'. I get one non-authoritative answer. When I type in 'nslookup -type=nds mit.edu', I get a bunch of non-authoritative answer name servers (8). So what is going is nslookup is sending out a command to my local dns to get all the name servers (both non-authoritative and authoritative name servers)?

Can someone let me know I am on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a non-authoritative list of authoritative name servers. Basically, it's saying "I am not authoritative, but here's what I believe the list of authoritative name servers are".

Comment: if I do a nslookup -type=NS somesite.com... The second part of the print out says: non-authoritative answer: somesite.com nameserver = ns1.1.com. The authoritative server is ns1.1.com?
thanks in advanced

Comment: @PeterSun The non authoritative answer is that the authoritative answer can be obtained from that nameserver.